# How to substitute "now" by a concrete datetime in Elasticsearch query?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elasticsearch-5

I want to substitute `now` by the datetime `2017-02-17T15:02:00` in the following query:

```
POST /myindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "range": {
        "date_range": {
            "field": "Datetime",
            "ranges": [
                { "to": "now-1H/H" }, 
                { "from": "now/H" } 
            ]
        }
    }
}
}
```

If I directly substitute `now` by `2017-02-17T15:02:00`, then the query fails with the error:

> type": "illegal_argument_exception", "reason": "Unrecognized chars at
>   the end of [2017-02-17T15:02:00/H]: [/H]"

Also, how can I specify the quarter of the hour instead of 1H?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [date math doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#date-math) states that

> The expression starts with an anchor date, which can either be `now`, or a date string ending with `||`.

which means that in your example, you have to substitute `now` by `2017-02-17T15:02:00||`

Try `{ "to": "2017-02-17T15:02:00||-1H/H" }`

To specify a quarter of an hour, use the minutes notation instead:
`{ "to": "2017-02-17T15:02:00||-15m/H" }`